# Http Kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, haproxy

Our application receives events through a HAProxy server on HTTPs, which should be forwarded and stored to Kafka cluster.

What should be the best option for this ?
This layer should receive events from HAProxy & produce them to Kafka cluster, in a reliable and efficient way (and should scale horizontally).

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to write a simple application in Java that just receives events and sends it to Kafka. The Java client for Kafka is the official client thus is the most reliable. The other option is to use an arbitrary language together with [the official Kafka REST Proxy](http://docs.confluent.io/1.0/platform.html#rest-proxy).

Every instance of the app should send the messages to all partitions based on some partition key. Then you can run multiple instances of the app and they don't even need to know about each other.

Comment: Thanks @Lukáš. Planning to use any open source component, just to make it reliable, scalable than our own custom code. Agree that Kafka Rest Proxy is an option. Other than these, can we use Flume, with a HTTP source and Kafka sink ?

Comment: I'm sorry I've never used Flume but I supposed it's possible. We use a simple Node.JS app for this purpose. It sends every message to Kafka using tha kafka-node client (but I don't think it's the most reliable client). But it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a simple application which consumes the messages from the **Proxy**
and send the response which you have obtained to the producer by setting the Kafka Configurations**producer.data()**. If the configurations are done successfully. you can able to consume the messages from the **Proxy server** which you use and see the response output in **/tmp/kafka-logs/topicname/00000000000000.log**.

this link will help you to tritw [enter link description here](https://www.codatlas.com/github.com/apache/kafka/HEAD/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples/Producer.java)

**Good Day**

**Keep Coding**